# 500 internal server error while trying to install Bolt 2.0.5

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error while trying to install Bolt.

1. First time Bolt user (been using Drupal for a few years).
2. I'm running on a VPS (with cPanel/WHM).
3. PHP version 5.4.37, Apache version 2.4.12
4. PHP memory_limit = 128M
5. PDO extension, curlssl extension, and GD extension are enabled
6. Chrome version 40.0.2214.111
7. mod_rewrite, SQLite, and MySQL 5.6.22
8. Downloaded the latest version and installed the traditional way (FTP)
9. Unzipped and updated permissions
10. .htaccess is there and looks the same as the one referenced on the Bolt installation page
11. I tried MySQL database and as-is to use SQLite database
12. Checked host configuration and AllowOverrides is enabled
13. tried enabling RewriteBase in .htaccess as well as the "FallbackResource /index.php" method
14. Bolt is in the root directory (not a subfolder)
15. I have PHP compiled as FCGI with suEXEC on and Ruid2 off.

All I get is the 500 Internal Server Error. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also having similar issues.

Comment: Nick, see answer below...just got it installed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just figured it out.

I disabled "Zend Guard Loader" on my VPS (cPanel/WHM >> EasyApache) and now I'm good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem with Bolt 3.0.0 today.

Was solved by removing

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
  Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

from .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Bold 2.2.20 today. If you're using cPanel, look for something like 'jail php for WordPress'. Disable that and you'll be ready to go.

Here's the description shown:

> This plugin will jail anonymous web page requests from users that are not logged in. Jailed requests will be read only, and linux will prevent writes to the filesystem. This will prevent almost all hacks.

Comment: Please look at this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be handy to lift your quality up